# Using fread() to parse data through a file and stdin

Tags: c, algorithm, file, stdin, fread

I am trying to write an algorithm that takes input from a file and builds what is called an "s1 record". (The functionality of this function is not important) Depending on the command line arguments, the program will set the inputFile to the specified file, or stdin if no file is provided.

The algorithm needs to be structured in a way that can handle both file patterns.

The idea of this is to take FILE* data and read it into a buffer of size 16 bytes. Every 16 bytes of data, an s1 record will be built. As long as there are 16 bytes to read then it works fine and dandy. Once there is a line with less than 16 bytes, it doesn't create an s1 record.

Ive tested the output and these are some of the things I noticed:

When I run the program using "stdin", I am prompted for user input. I enter 20 characters (which should print 16 in 1 srecord, and 4 in another) and my output is as follows:

```
12345678901234567890
Buffer: 1234567890123456
S113000031323334353637383930313233343536AA
```

When I run the program using a file (record.dat) with one single line with the characters of the alphabet on it, I get this:

```
Buffer: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
Buffer: QRSTUVWXYZKLMNOP
```

This is not valid either, as it prints the "KLMNOP" at the end of the line as well.

My question is: How can I structure this to accept the input from either a file or stdin using the same algorithm, and what exactly am I doing wrong in my algorithm? I have tried providing all the useful information I can, and can specify more detail if requested. Below is the code for the algorithm I am trying to write.

**inputFile is set to stdin if no file is specified**

```
    char buffer[kMaxLineSize + 1] = { '\0' };
    char byte = 0;

    int count = 1;

    while((fread(buffer, 1, kMaxLineSize, inputFile)))
    {
        printf("%c", byte);

        clearCRLF(buffer);
        printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);

        if(outputFormat == 1)
        {
            char s1Record[kMaxSRecordSize] = { 0 };
            buildS1Record(addressField, s1Record, buffer);

            fprintf(outputFile, "%s\n", s1Record);

            addressField += strlen(buffer);
            s1Count++;
        }
        else
        {
            char asmRecord[kMaxASMRecordSize] = { 0 };
            buildAssemblyRecord(asmRecord, buffer);

            fprintf(outputFile, "%s\n", asmRecord);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggest you debug one problem at a time and ask one question at a time. For the second question you are asking what is wrong in the implementation of the algorithm but you have not fully described what the algorithm is to transform the input to the output. You've said "Every 16 bytes of data, an s1 record will be built" but you haven't told us what an "s1 record" is exactly. Maybe you think its not important what an "s1 record" is but we need to at least understand how to interpret the sample output. As it is, you say the output is wrong but we don't know what the right output supposed to be.

Comment: The s1 record is irrelevent in this question I'm wondering about parsing the input into arrays of 16 bytes.. I just said that so people wouldn't ask me what the builds1record function was. Im sorry its really late can you bare with me?

Comment: All it needs to do is essentially split the data every 16 bytes and create the array of the 16 bytes and pass it to a "magical function" that turns it into an srecord. Its the whole fread() thing that I need to understand

Comment: Perhaps you can come back to ask again when you are more alert. Your question is not vary coherent at the moment. Now you are asking about parsing arrays when the question title is asking something about stdin vs file input. For the parsing problem it really is not clear what the issues is. Why can't you process 16 bytes at a time? The `fread` tells you how much data was read. Just keep processing 16 bytes until the remaining bytes are less than 16.

Comment: If I do this, the remaining 4 bytes or so will not be read? How can I work around this? I had tried this earlier

Comment: Read a *maximum* of 16 bytes at a time. If the `fread` return 16 then process it. If it return less than 16 the remaining input was consumed but you can drop it and you are done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105080/discussion-between-kyle-jensen-and-kaylum).

Comment: I want the remaining input to be parsed though

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to combine the comments in this answer.

But first, what you call an s1 "record" is not a record. It is a string of maximum 16 characters and a terminating null character. A record, in my understanding, is a struct with fields of possibly different types, one of which could be a string.

The code fixes are as follows:

```
char buffer[kMaxLineSize + 1] = { '\0' };
int len;
while (len=fread(buffer, 1, kMaxLineSize, inputFile))
{
    ...
    char s1Record[kMaxSRecordSize] = { 0 };
    buildS1Record(addressField, s1Record, buffer, len);
```

so you pass the length read to the function. Now it can copy the characters read and terminate with a `'\0'` character. Note also that there can be a discrepancy between `kMaxLineSize` and `kMaxSRecordSize`: they must be the same size (plus 1 for `\0`), so better use a single variable.

I hope this late answer can still be of use to you.